Firestore deadlocks when querying concurrently from multiple threads
I am getting a very stable deadlock when trying to retrieve Firestore document snapshots from multiple threads concurrently. Here is a little artificial example that reproduces the problem.
import threading
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore


__app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(credentials.ApplicationDefault())

# Firestore query function
def query_firestore(docid):
    db = firestore.client(__app)
    coll = db.collection("mycollection")
    try:
        print("About to query firestore")
        doc = coll.document(docid).get().to_dict()
        # The flow never reaches here.
        print(f"Document data: {doc}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error querying Firestore: {e}")


# Function to create and start N threads
def start_threads(n, docid):
    threads = []
    for _ in range(n):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=query_firestore, args=(docid,))
        threads.append(thread)
        thread.start()
    # Wait for all threads to complete
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 5  # Number of threads
    docid = "1234"
    start_threads(N, docid)

When I desynchronize the threads, introducing waits, the deadlock, obviously, doesn't occur. I tried this with versions 2.15.0 and 2.16.0 of google-cloud-firestore.
This looks like a bug in the firestore library, but perhaps I'm doing something stupid here.

If you think there is a bug, you should report that directly to the authors of the library.  In this case, it looks like filing an issue on GitHub would be best.  We can't really help you if don't think the problem is with your own code and are able to share your debugging details.  I'm voting to close as such.

My thinking here is that many other developers must be using firestore in multi-threaded application, so there must be another way of doing this that doesn't lead to a deadlock. I will definitely file a bug, as even if such other way exists, it should be more prominently documented.
